# Why is WordPress encoding ampersands in URLs?

Tags: html, wordpress

WordPress is changing the actual location for a link I used in tablepress. I get a page not found.

File Name -
`https://ebiznet.sbc.com/calnetinfo/Uploads/Link/Catalog_B_AT&T_Legacy_Cat%2015_Dedicated%20Transport_20190729.pdf`

WordPress changes the file name with & to `&amp;`

`https://ebiznet.sbc.com/calnetinfo/Uploads/Link/Catalog_B_AT&amp;T_Legacy_Cat%2015_Dedicated%20Transport_20190729.pdf`

Comment: Did you paste the wrong link the second time? both links are working for me. Paste the link the Wordpress is displaying incorrectly.

Comment: Stackoverflow automatically converts `&amp;` to `&` so both these links look the same. Editing the question shows that @JimBob was having issues with url encoding / html entities